# How do i change the visibilty and size of css object with c#

Tags: c#, css

I have a div with id _box1

My on click event accesses the c# routine below:

```
private void Expand_Ratings(object src, EventArgs e)
    {

        _box1.Style["background-color"] = "Red";

    }
```

when I run the compiler I get:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name '_box1' does not exist in the current context
```

Can anyone please assist

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `runat="server"` attribute to the  tag in HTML code tobe accessible from server side code.

Try This:

```
<DIV ID="_box1" runat="server">

</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `runat="server"` to your div.

And then you should do this:

```
_box1.Attrbutes["style"] = "background-color:red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes at runat server in the div.

```
<div ID="_box1" runat="server">

</div>
```

In the code behind..

```
_box1.Width = 300;
_box1.Height = 300;
_box1.Visible = false;

or by CSS
_box1.Style["Height"] = "300px";
_box1.Style["Visible"] = "false";
```

Good luke